# Web Performance Test for SharePoint Online sites to measure performance

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, load-testing, visual-studio-2017, security-testing-o365

I created a Web Performance and Load Test Project in VS2017 to test the performance of SharePoint Online sites for CRUD operations.

But Test fails due to SharePoint Online tenant authentication issue.
Though I provided the user name and password in properties of test set, it fails.

I would like to compare the performance metrics between 2 different site templates (Document center vs Team Site).

Answer (score 0):

Load tesing Office 365 isn't allowed see [Capacity planning and load testing SharePoint Online](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/capacity-planning-and-load-testing-sharepoint-online-c932bd9b-fb9a-47ab-a330-6979d03688c0)

If you want to compare different pages, then out can use my [sharepoint-wpt-cookies](https://github.com/singingknight/sharepoint-wpt-cookies) in combination with [WebPageTest](https://www.webpagetest.org/) to get some detailed reports